# Read http://example.com/uploads/2014/07/what-makes-people-happy1.jpg

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

How do I get:

```
http://example.com/uploads/2014/07/what-makes-people-happy1.jpg
```

from:

```
http://example.com/uploads/2014/07/what-makes-people-happy1-300*200.jpg
```

In PHP and `300*200` is not constant as this is height and width

```
Edit:

$xpath = new DOMXPath(@DOMDocument::loadHTML($content));

$src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");

$src=preg_replace('~-\d+\*\d+(?=\.)~', '',$src);

echo $src;
```

Comment: that url does not work, show this message `Example Domain - 

This domain is established to be used for illustrative examples in documents. You may use this domain in examples without prior coordination or asking for permission.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `preg_replace` function to remove the image resolution,

```
<?php
echo preg_replace('~-\d+\*\d+(?=\.)~', '', 'http://example.com/uploads/2014/07/what-makes-people-happy1-300*200.jpg');
?> //=> http://example.com/uploads/2014/07/what-makes-people-happy1.jpg
```

**Explanation:**

- `-\d+` One or more digits preceded by a `-` symbol.
- `\*` Matches the Literal `*`  symbol.
- `\d+` Matches one or more digits.
- `(?=\.)` Lookahead asserts that the following character must be be a dot.

Comment: post the value of `$src` after running `$src = $xpath->evaluate("string(//img/@src)");` code.

Comment: sorry its my mistake the url is like http:.../2014/07/what-makes-people-happy1-300x200.jpg not 300*200

Comment: then your regex would be `~-\d+x\d+(?=\.)~`

Comment: I replaced * with x in preg_replace function but still not successful

Comment: Ya got it..Thank you so much for ur kind help

Comment: not `\x` it,s `x` only. See http://regex101.com/r/dI1xA7/3 . [And accept my answer if it helps you.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Sorry to ask this.. I am new to stackoverflow. Where can i have option to accept you ans..I am not able to see